# Most secure way to pass variables between two pages with PHP

Tags: php, security, variables

I need a way to pass a variable between two page in a secure way.

I know that I can use POST / GET / Cookie / Session or hidden fields but I think none of these ways aren't secure enough because :

get can be seen in the url
cookies is a client side so it can be change from client
session can confront Session ID hijacking and ...

Now I want to know is there another ways better than these ways and if there isn't witch of these is the best way to pass variables in secure manner;

Comment: Sessions.  If you don't trust them, then I think you're out of options.

Comment: Sessions are your friend on php (server-side) / alternative take a look in the html5 web storage http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp

Comment: Definitely sessions. Interested read: http://cleverlogic.net/tutorials/session-hijacking-0.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Session is the most secure method you have available.

Session id regeneration will help against session hijacking, but SSL via https will really protect against it.

BTW: If the session is hijacked and you're displaying user data to the client, it doesn't matter how you got the data to the second page, the hijacker will see it.  If you're only using it server side, the hijacker won't see it.

Comment: regenerating session ID would be helpful in preventing the eavesdropping only if the after login section runs TLS. If the regenerated ID is copied from browser location and then replayed in another browser I assume login will still happen irrespective of TLS or not.. am I correct?

Answer (score 3):

Passing variable values between pages using session is most secure

and Regenerate the session id by [`session_regenerate_id`](https://www.php.net/session_regenerate_id) whenever the security level changes (such as logging in). You can even regenerate the session id every request if you wish.

Good Read

[**PHP Security Guide: Sessions**](http://phpsec.org/projects/guide/4.html)

Answer (score 1):

since session is server side, its the most secure way to pass the variables
and to prevent session hijacking you can use session_regenerate_id function in php
the manual: http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-regenerate-id.php

but that doesn't means you always use sessions to pass variables
you still can use cookies, but encrypt the data before storing them in the cookies.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with using GET - as long as they are sanitised correctly... you can always combine get with a hash of the parameters to reduce the risk of it being tampered with, along with use of sessions to ensure they are also legitimate.