# EDIT data with php code saving issue

Tags: php, sql, sql-update, sql-delete

This is my Form page editFormpackage.php
I can bring my data back into a form for updating   but when i change the values and click update the iformation doesn't  save.Can someone please help!Im new to php.

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title> AB Delivery </title>
<title> *Please enter details of employee took order. </title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title> AB Delivery </title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
<link href= rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<!-- jQuery file -->
<script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.tabify.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var $ = jQuery.noConflict();
$(function() {
$('#tabsmenu').tabify();
$(".toggle_container").hide(); 
$(".trigger").click(function(){
    $(this).toggleClass("active").next().slideToggle("slow");
    return false;
});
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="panelwrap">

    <div class="header">
    <div class="title"><a href="#">AB Delivery</a></div>

    <div class="header_right">Welcome Admin </div>

    <div class="menu">
    <ul>
    <li><a href="http://localhost/delivery2/homepage.html" class="selected">New Entry</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://localhost/delivery2/showall.php">Show All</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://localhost/delivery2/edit.php">Edit</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://localhost/delivery2/search.html">Search</a></li>
    </ul>
    </div>


   <div class="center_content">  

    <div id="right_wrap">
    <div id="left_content">             
    <h2>Tables section</h2> 


<table id="rounded-corner">



<?php
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }

mysql_select_db("delivery", $con);

if(isset($_GET['package_id']))
{
$package_id=$_GET['package_id'];
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
$customer_id=$_POST['customer_id'];
$order_taken_by_employee_id=$_POST['order_taken_by_employee_id'];
$package_details=$_POST['package_details'];
$result=mysql_query("UPDATE package SET customer_id ='$customer_id',order_taken_by_employee_id='$order_taken_by_employee_id', package_details='$package_details' where package_id='$package_id'");
if($result)
{
header('location:edit.php');
}
}
$query1=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM package  WHERE package_id='$package_id'");
$query2=mysql_fetch_array($query1);
?>
<form method="post" action="http://localhost/delivery2/editFormpackage.php">
Customer ID:<input type="text" name="customer_id" value="<?php echo $query2['customer_id']; ?>" /><br />
Order Taken by Employee ID:<input type="text" name="order_taken_by_employee_id" value="<?php echo $query2['order_taken_by_employee_id']; ?>" /><br /><br />
Package Details:<input type="text" name="package_details" value="<?php echo $query2['package_details']; ?>" /><br /><br />
<br />
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="update" />
</form>


<?php
}
?>



 <div 



    <div class="clear"></div>
    </div> <!--end of center_content-->

    <div class="footer">
AB Delivery 
</div>

</div>


</body>
</html>
```

This is the code from edit.php as you can see i created a new page for all the tables to be updated .

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title> AB Delivery </title>
<title> *Please enter details of employee took order. </title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title> AB Delivery </title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
<link href= rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<!-- jQuery file -->
<script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.tabify.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var $ = jQuery.noConflict();
$(function() {
$('#tabsmenu').tabify();
$(".toggle_container").hide(); 
$(".trigger").click(function(){
    $(this).toggleClass("active").next().slideToggle("slow");
    return false;
});
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="panelwrap">

    <div class="header">
    <div class="title"><a href="#">AB Delivery</a></div>

    <div class="header_right">Welcome Admin </div>

    <div class="menu">
    <ul>
    <li><a href="http://localhost/delivery2/homepage.html" class="selected">New Entry</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://localhost/delivery2/showall.php">Show All</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://localhost/delivery2/edit.php">Edit</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://localhost/delivery2/search.html">Search</a></li>
    </ul>
    </div>


   <div class="center_content">  

    <div id="right_wrap">
    <div id="left_content">             
    <h2>Tables section</h2> 


<table id="rounded-corner">


<?php
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }

mysql_select_db("delivery", $con);

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM customers");



echo "<table border='19'>
<tr>
<th>Customer ID</th>
<th>Customer Address ID</th>
<th>Name</th>
<th>Phone Number</th>
<th>Email</th>
<th>Action</th>
</tr>";

while($row1 = mysql_fetch_array($result))

  {
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td>" . $row1['customer_id'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row1['customer_address_id'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row1['customer_name'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row1['customer_phone'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row1['customer_email'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td><a href='editFormcustomers.php?customer_id=".$row1['customer_id']."'>Edit</a></td>";
echo "<td><a href='deletecustomers.php?customer_id=".$row1['customer_id']."'>x</a></td><tr>";
  }


echo "</tr>";

echo "</table>";

mysql_close($con);

?>

<?php
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }

mysql_select_db("delivery", $con);

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM address");



echo "<table border='19'>
<tr>
<th>Address ID</th>
<th>Address </th>
<th>Action</th>
</tr>";

while($row2 = mysql_fetch_array($result))

  {
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td>" . $row2['address_id'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row2['line_1'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td><a href='editFormaddress.php?address_id=".$row2['address_id']."'>Edit</a></td>";
echo "<td><a href='deleteaddress.php?address_id=".$row2['address_id']."'>x</a></td><tr>";
  }


echo "</tr>";

echo "</table>";

mysql_close($con);

?>

<?php
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }

mysql_select_db("delivery", $con);

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM package");



echo "<table border='19'>
<tr>
<th>Packasge ID</th>
<th> Customer ID</th>
<th>Employee ID</th>
<th>Details</th>
<th>Action</th>
</tr>";

while($row3 = mysql_fetch_array($result))

  {
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td>" . $row3['package_id'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row3['customer_id'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row3['order_taken_by_employee_id'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row3['package_details'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td><a href='editFormpackage.php?package_id=".$row3['package_id']."'>Edit</a></td>";
echo "<td><a href='deletepackage.php?package_id=".$row3['package_id']."'>x</a></td><tr>";


  }


echo "</tr>";

echo "</table>";

mysql_close($con);

?>

<?php
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }

mysql_select_db("delivery", $con);

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM employee");



echo "<table border='19'>
<tr>
<th>Employee ID</th>
<th>Employee Name</th>
<th>Phone Number</th>
<th>Other Details</th>
<th>Action</th>
</tr>";

while($row4 = mysql_fetch_array($result))

  {
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td>" . $row4['employee_id'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row4['employee_name'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row4['employee_phone'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row4['other_employee_details'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td><a href='editFormemployee.php?employee_id=".$row4['employee_id']."'>Edit</a></td>";
echo "<td><a href='deleteemployee.php?employee_id=".$row4['employee_id']."'>x</a></td><tr>";

  }


echo "</tr>";

echo "</table>";


mysql_close($con);

?>


  <div 



    <div class="clear"></div>
    </div> <!--end of center_content-->

    <div class="footer">
AB Delivery 
</div>

</div>


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The where clause in your update script references a package id, however nowhere is the package id being set in the form.

```
$result=mysql_query("UPDATE package SET customer_id ='$customer_id',order_taken_by_employee_id='$order_taken_by_employee_id', package_details='$package_details' where package_id='$package_id'");
```

Before we get to the solution I have to point out that you are extremely vulnerable to SQL injection since you are not sanitizing your form input before going straight to the DB with it. Check this out to help get you on the right track there https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php

The solution below will work, but passing the package id in POST can technically be hacked as well.  Passing IDs in a server or DB session is the most secure ([Most secure way to pass variables between two pages with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13142054/most-secure-way-to-pass-variables-between-two-pages-with-php)), however the solution below will get you on your way.

You're setting package id from a GET query parameter but once your form submits, it will submit to the URL defined in the form action parameter, which as you can see does not still include the package id.

To solve this you should add the package_id as a hidden form variable like so:

```
<form method="post" action="http://localhost/delivery2/editFormpackage.php">
 Customer ID:<input type="text" name="customer_id" value="<?php echo     $query2['customer_id']; ?>" /><br />
Order Taken by Employee ID:<input type="text" name="order_taken_by_employee_id" value="<?php echo $query2['order_taken_by_employee_id']; ?>" /><br /><br />
Package Details:<input type="text" name="package_details" value="<?php echo $query2['package_details']; ?>" /><br /><br />
<br />
<input type="hidden" name="package_id" value="<?php echo $query2['package_id'];?>" />
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="update" />
</form>
```

And then set the package_id from the package_id in the $_POST superglobal like so:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
$package_id = $_POST['package_id'];
$customer_id=$_POST['customer_id'];
$order_taken_by_employee_id=$_POST['order_taken_by_employee_id'];
$package_details=$_POST['package_details'];
$result=mysql_query("UPDATE package SET customer_id ='$customer_id',order_taken_by_employee_id='$order_taken_by_employee_id', package_details='$package_details' where package_id='$package_id'");
// rest of your code
```

Comment: Thanks,but its still not saving the data .

Comment: Are you getting any type of error?  Can you also post the updates you made to your script?

Answer (score 0):

This is the correct code:

```
 <form method="post" action="http://localhost/delivery2/editFormpackage.php">
         Customer ID:<input type="text" name="customer_id" value="<?php echo     $query2['customer_id']; ?>" /><br />
        Order Taken by Employee ID:<input type="text" name="order_taken_by_employee_id" value="<?php echo $query2['order_taken_by_employee_id']; ?>" /><br /><br />
        Package Details:<input type="text" name="package_details" value="<?php echo $query2['package_details']; ?>" /><br /><br />
        <br />
        <input type="hidden" name="package_id" value="<?php echo $query2['package_id'];?>" />
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="update" />
        </form>
```